# Buildozer error while compiling for Android

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy, buildozer

I am trying to compile a Kivy app to an Android apk. I get the following error at the very end of the process. Can someone please advise? The buildozer on-screen debug log and buildozer spec files are attached for reference.

Please advise.

Following is the buildozer error log:

Error: ERROR: /home/neo/code/siva-android/v1.1/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/SIVAv1.1__armeabi-v7a/gradlew failed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the issue with help of a person on a Kivy forum. It was due to an incorrect specification of the package name in the Buildozer spec file. Special characters are not allowed.

```
package.name: String, package name.

The Package name is one word with only ASCII characters and/or numbers. It should not contain any special characters. For example, if your application is named Flat Jewels, the package name can be flatjewels.
```

[Buildozer app specifications](https://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/specifications.html#section-app)

Comment: Thank you! Same problem for me. I got an apostrophe and an exclamation mark in the name app, and those characters gave the error.